# How to compare the DialogField value between a string with a difference uppercase?

Tags: dialog, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, uppercase

I have this little question,

how I can compare the dialogField.Value() with my String, I need to have a difference between **uppercase** .

I used this code, but I haven't strictness, I have the **true** return in both case , upper and lower case.

```
dialogField = dialog.addFieldValue(extendedTypeStr(String30), text);
if (dialogField.value() == "TEXTCONFIRM")
{
 //other code
}
```

Thanks for your help,

enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a case sensitive string comparison in AX, use the `strCmp` function:

```
if (strCmp(dialogField.value(), "TEXTCONFIRM") == 0)
{
    // other code
}
```

See [X++, C# Comparison: String Case and Delimiters [AX 2012]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc967424.aspx) and [strCmp Function [AX 2012]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa672979.aspx)

Comment: FH-Inway thank you for your solution, and even more for the technical-developper Web Page! Enjoy!